# how can I append this tree data using jquery recursively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, recursion

```
[{"tag":35,"value":"W","children":[
    {"tag":55,"value":"GOOG","children":null},
    {"tag":262,"value":"ghost332002m0","children":null},
    {"tag":268,"value":"1","children":[
       {"tag":269,"value":"B","children":null},
       {"tag":271,"value":"0","children":null},
       {"tag":336,"value":"3","children":null}
     ]}
  ]},
   {"tag":35,"value":"W","children":[
       {"tag":55,"value":"GOOG","children":null},
       {"tag":262,"value":"ghost332002m0","children":null},
       {"tag":268,"value":"0","children":null}
   ]} 
]
```

There's the JSON, it's FIX Market Data and you have these nested groups, so this is my representation of these FIX messages in JSON. Anyway, I send it to my web client and need to flatten it back out in the display.

```
$.getJSON('/receive', function(data, returnValue) {
    $.each(data, function(index,value) {
        $('#output').append('<p>');
        appendStuff(value);
        $('#output').append('</p>');
    });
function appendStuff(children) {
    debug_var.push(children);
    $.each(children, function(child) {
        $('#output').append(child.tag+'='+child.value+' ');
        if (child.children != null) {
            appendStuff(child.children);
        }
    })
}
```

I'm trying to use recursion to spin through this data and print everything out. What I get is:

```
undefined=undefined undefined=undefined undefined=undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Oh, the data is all there in debug_var...

[image]

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work like HTML. You are misusing `append` method. Can you post the expected markup?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. $('#output').append(variable); injects the contents of variable into my <div id='output'>

Comment: One thing I notice is that appendStuff takes children array as argument, but when it called with value instead.

Comment: Also in $.each the first argument of the callback is numeric index and not the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something closer to

```
$.getJSON('/receive', function (data) {
    $.each(data, function(index,value) {
        $('#output').append('<p>');
        appendStuff(value.children || []);
        $('#output').append('</p>');
    });
    function appendStuff(children) {
        $.each(children, function(i, child) {
            $('#output').append(child.tag+'='+child.value+' ');
            if (child.children != null) {
                appendStuff(child.children);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

*Note the above does not print the tags of parents, you may want to add that.*